# Problem displaying related foreignkey data in Django Admin screen

Tags: django-admin

To display foreignkey data in my admin list view, I created a callable:

```
def next_date(self):
    EvDateObj = EventDate.objects.filter(event__id__exact=self.id)
        .exclude(event_date__lt=datetime.date.today())
        .order_by('event_date')[:1]
    return EvDateObj
```

This shows in the list view as:

```
[<EventDate: 25 September 2010>]
```

Which is the unicode string for the EventDate model (25 Sept 2010), with some django-generated object stuff around it: `[< EventDate ______ >]`

If I modify the callable return statement to try and just get the date itself:

```
return EvDateObj.event_date
```

or

```
return EvDateObj.event_date.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

the admin list view simply shows:

```
(None)
```

Any thoughts?  I am unsure how to proceed because I can get the desired object, but cannot access any of its properties without triggering the "(None)" result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    EvDateObj = EventDate.objects.get(event__id__exact=self.id)
    .exclude(event_date__lt=datetime.date.today())
    .order_by('event_date')[:1]
```

objects.filter() always returns a QuerySet (similar to a Python List), even if there is only 1 result. EDateObj.objects.get() will return an object.

Alternatively you can do:

```
return EvDateObj[0]
```

I haven't tried it myself, so hope this works for you.